# Open close sidebar clicking anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a sidebar that can be able to close it clicking on the X button and clicking anywhere
I am able to close the navbar by clicking on the X button in the sidebar. How can I change my javascript to be able to close the sidebar by clicking anywhere on the page?

```js
 function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="250px";
 }
 function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="0"
 }
```

```css
 
 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
 }

 .sidenav a{

  display: block;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: 0.3s;
 }
 
 .sidenav a:hover{

  color: #F1F1F1;

 } 

 .sidenav .closebtn{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 50px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px){

  .sidenav{padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a{font-size: 18px;}

 }
```

```html
<body>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 1</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 2</a>

</div>
<h2>Animated Sidenav</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open sidenav</p>
<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openNav()">cart</span>




</body>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element Most of it is jQuery, but I think there are some plain JS answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to clicks on your entire page through:

```
document.body.onclick = function () {
  // Close Nav here
}
```

However, doing this will cause your entire page to try to close the nav when clicked – even your open button.

You can exclude certain elements from listening to events set on parent elements through the `e.stopPropagation()` method. See an example implementation below.

Please also note that your body will not start off 100% of your window's height due to the lack of content, and thus will not respond to clicks everywhere on the page. You can fix this by using setting the CSS property `body: 100vh`.

```js
function openNav(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="250px";
}
 
function closeNav(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="0"
}

document.body.onclick = closeNav;
document.getElementsByClassName('openbtn')[0].onclick = openNav;
document.getElementById('mySidenav').onclick = openNav;
document.getElementsByClassName('closebtn')[0].onclick = closeNav;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
}

.sidenav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
 
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #F1F1F1;
} 

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav{padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a{font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 1</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 2</a>

</div>
<h2>Animated Sidenav</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open sidenav</p>
<span style="cursor: pointer;" class="openbtn">cart</span>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can add overlay element when the sidebar is shown.

```js
function overlay(isShow){
  var elm = document.getElementById('overlay')
  if (isShow) {
    elm.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elm.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function openNav() {
  overlay(true);
 document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  overlay(false);
 document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="0"
}
```

```css
 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
 }

 .sidenav a{

  display: block;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: 0.3s;
 }
 
 .sidenav a:hover{

  color: #F1F1F1;

 } 

 .sidenav .closebtn{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 50px;
 }
  
  #overlay{
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
  }

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px){

  .sidenav{padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a{font-size: 18px;}

 }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 1</a>
 <a href="#">CARRITO 2</a>
</div>
<h2>Animated Sidenav</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open sidenav</p>
<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openNav()">cart</span>
<div id="overlay" onclick="closeNav()"></div>
```